# can we use bitlocker on external hdd of 1TB

Tags: disk-encryption, usb-storage, bitlocker

I thought of using Bitlocker on my new Western Digital(My Passport) external HDD. It is powered through USB and no separate power source.

I searched in the internet related to this and saw few posts stating not to use Bitlocker on external devices especially WD because it has caused a lot of trouble. Seems to be that few had experienced it.

When i checked further i could see that there is another version called 'Bitlocker To Go' which can be used on USB devices. The demonstrations talk about USB devices mostly sticks of 2GB to 16GB.

Though my External HDD is also an USB device i have a confusion whether to use Bitlocker or 'Bitlocker To Go'.

Suggestions please.

Comment: What trouble would it cause exactly link to what you read.

Comment: It should work fine. BitLocker To Go is a special version of BitLocker that writes a small application that can allow XP, Vista, Win 7 Home Premium to READ ONLY the data on the USB.

Answer (score 0):

> Though my External HDD is also an USB device i have a confusion
>   whether to use Bitlocker or 'Bitlocker To Go'.
>
> Suggestions please.

I have used Bitlocker To-Go on external portable USB Western Digital hard drives of various sizes (~500 GB) without encountering any problems. You should be fine using Bitlocker To-Go.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure the OP has already determined his answer by now but I thought that I would throw in my example. I have a 2TB My Passport as well as a 500 GB My Book from WD. Both of them are hardware encrypted using 256 bit AES hardware encryption from WD. However the firmware running the chip that allows this encryption has proven easy to exploit so I ALSO encrypted it using Bitlocker To Go. Both drives run fine and none of my ahem, "experienced" friends have been able to exploit my drives since. Only word of caution I would give is that when dealing with a TB or more of memory, I would run the encryption process from a PC you do not plan to use for a day or two ie: not your daily driver. It can take.....well, forever.

Comment: Answers are not meant to share your 2 cents with the world.  Its to answer the author's question.  You should edit your answer, so that it answers the author's question,  There are already two answers that indicate it will work with the drives, so be sure you offer something different, then the existing answers.